# Special characters in Sed's replacement space

Tags: sed

Reading sed manual, It seems only \ and & are to be watch out for in *replacement space* when using the s command in sed.

Are there any other characters having special meaning in *replacement space*? (Affecting the replacement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short Answer: You need to quote '\' '&' and new line.

Long Answer: The 'sed' man page indicates

```
   To include a literal '\', '&', or newline in the final replacement,
be sure to precede the desired '\', '&', or newline in the REPLACEMENT
with a '\'.
```

Implying all other characters are valid literals in the REPLACEMENT string.

Comment: If \ is quoted, \n is therefore Quoted too at that point.
Does "newline" mean something else in the answer(s)?

Comment: @DegenWoW - newline refers to "simple" new line, which can not be placed into the REPLACEMENT part. If you do not quote it, it will be interpreted as the end of a sed command. In other words, you can not type 's/A/<newline>/' (it will produce 'unterminated 's' command). As you have indicated, you can use \n to force a newline to the REPLACEMENT